# Automatic image straightening for documents

Tags: gratis, image-editor

Is there a software which, for documents, automatically determines the angle of rotation and straightens the image?

Some applications are able to rotate image by externally given angle.  The best I found is Rotation Pilot which lets the user to draw a straight line and makes this line horizontal. If I understood correctly, the precision is 0.1 degree (e.g., it can rotate   by 0.8 or 0.9 degrees, but not 0.85), which is not that good.  I want the application to determine the rotation angle without my intervention. For documents, it is not that hard.

(Also interested about similar application for other images: photographs of people and animals, landscapes, etc.)

The software should preferably run under Windows 10. Ubuntu under Windows 10 (WSL) would be acceptable, too. I am not ready to pay, so it must come free of charge.

Comment: What OS should it run on? Any price considerations (how much you'd be willing to pay if needed)?

Comment: Windows 10. Or maybe Ubuntu under Windows 10.  I am not ready to pay.

Comment: Thanks! I've **[edit]ed** your question accordingly, please check if it fits.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the shellscript [TEXTDESKEW](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textdeskew/index.php) can help?

It runs from the command line and uses [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).

Please consider the respective Licenses.